# Cannot resolve method 'entrySet()' in Map<>

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to print some values using Map.But I am getting the following error.

**Cannot resolve method 'entrySet()'**

```
 List<Map<Integer, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
        contactList = (List<Map<Integer, List<EffectList>>>) new  HashMap<Integer,List<EffectList>>();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<EffectList>> entry : contactList.entrySet())
        {
            //code here
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `contactList` is a `List`, not a `Map`. I'm very surprised you didn't get a `ClassCastException` there, trying to cast a `HashMap` to a variable of type `List`.

Comment: Why are you casting a `HashMap` to a `List`?

Comment: @Andreas It didn't pass compilation, so they didn't get that far.

Comment: You are casting a Hasmap tolist, and calling .entrySet() on List not Map.

Comment: @Eran DOH! Of course. I'm seeing the *next* error, huh.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Map<Integer, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
contactList = (List<Map<Integer, List<EffectList>>>) new  HashMap<Integer,List<EffectList>>();
```

you are doing wrong in initialization as because List can not be initialize by a Hash Map .

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Map<Integer, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
 contactList = (List<Map<Integer, List<EffectList>>>) new  HashMap<Integer,List<EffectList>>();
```

So you cast the `Map` to a `List` and the `List` doesn't have `entrySet()` method.
There is no reason to cast a `Map` to a `List` of `Map`s

Replace those lines with:

```
Map<Integer, List<EffectList>> contactList;
contactList = new  HashMap<Integer,List<EffectList>>();
```